# where is there any decent TouchXML examples / tutorials

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, touchxml

I'm trying to see how this works but as yet all I seem to find is dead links, fragmented comments or nothing of any worth to introduce a beginner to this?

Any pointers welcome, thanks

Answer (score 5):

http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/

edit: also check posts in the same website under the TouchXML tag.